# Session destroy every time when page refresh

Tags: php, session

I am making admin panel there I implement login area when all information match to the database i mean login information username and password than i start session and redirect to index page but extremely confused why session null when i page refresh actually on index page i check that if session null than page redirect to login page.also using `session_start();` on every page.i have been checked php.ini for lifetime there life time set 1440 default.

**checking.php**

```
session_start();

if((!empty($result)) && (!empty($result2))){
  $_SESSION['admin'] = $user;
  header("location:../../index.php");
 }

else {

    echo "Something wrong";

    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['admin'] == null)
{
header("location:system/access/login.php");
 }
require('../config.php');
require('system/classes/userdata.php');
?>
```

Any one now the solution.

Answer (score 1):

checking.php

```
//session should be started before every thing.

  session_start();


if((!empty($result)) && (!empty($result2))){
  $_SESSION['admin'] = $user;
  header("location:../../index.php");
 }

else {

    echo "Something wrong";

    }
```

Comment: Sorry above code i wrote wrong in real code session_start(); i am using on top.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its because of the null thing, try this

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin']){
        //write your code
     }
```

Reason being that a NULL is not equal to a NULL

Answer (score 0):

@Mubo, session should not be started before everything, especially if you store objects in session.

@user3163274, this can be problem with sessions configuration, it can be badly configured cookies, or perhaps you got session cookies disabled at all (by default cookies are enabled). Problem can be caused by data you hold in session (especially if you hold there objects).

But if i can suggest, stop using relative paths for includes/requires and redirections. Also, if you want to test data against nulls use equality operator like === (it also checks the type)